# selective css (link tag) for div

Tags: html, css

Can I have a  css tag on my page, that is applied selectively to some div element on that page only.

Say it has some entry like

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I do not want this property to be applied on all the elements on that page.

Comment: For clarification on what I want : I have a container div on my page, in which I am copying text from a site (with its style) and also applying that site's css to my page (which contains the container div). Now if the css downloaded from that site has something like * { margin :o;}, then this css changes look and feel of my page (page which has container div) as well, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign id to the divs you want to apply css individually and seperately.
and you must assign class to a set of elements if you want to apply some css to that set collectively.

It will not apply on all elements in that page.

ID method:

```
#div{
margin: 0;
}
```

Class method:

```
.div{
margin: 50;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div"> </div>
<div class="test"> </div>
<div class="test"> </div>
<div class="test"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying it to one specific div, but not to any others, you might as well put it in-line

```
<div style="margin:0"> .....  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this case you can do it

```
<div id="someId" style="margin:0"> </div>
```

Comment: I have a container div on my page, in which I am copying text from a site (with its style) and also applying that site's css to my page (which contains the container div). Now if the css downloaded from that site has something like * { margin :o;}, then this css changes look and feel of my page (page which has container div) as well, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're positive you're only going to be using it on one element, just use an inline style like other said:

```
<div style="margin:0;"> Your Content </div>
```

If you're going to be using it on more than once, make a class in CSS,

```
.nomargin {
    margin: 0;
}
```

and then use it by calling that class:

```
<div class="nomargin"> Your Content </div>
```

This will ensure that you can make changes to all of these classes at once if you need to change something in the future.  ALWAYS use an external style if there will be more than one element using it, it will save you so many headaches in the long run.